# Prove If $A^{2014}$ is invertible, then $A$ is also invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Use the associativity of matrix multiplication to prove that if $A^{2014}$ is invertible, then $A$ is also invertible.

Any help please?

Comment: Try multiplying $(A^{-1})^{2014}$ to it.

Comment: @chriseur, you've got the problem backwards.

Comment: @vadim123: yes, totally, sorry.  Mark's solution below does the job.

Comment: If you were freer in your choice of solution method, this would be my suggestion: if a linear transformation of $\Bbb R^n$ applied $2014$ times doesn't collapse any dimensions, then just applying it once wouldn't collapse anything either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is another way, even though **Mark Bennet** is more elementary and perfectly clear.

I'm using the properties of the function "$det$" defined over the set of square matrix with value in the base field.

By [Cauchy - Binet formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula) $$det(AB)=det(A)det(B)$$ So in this problem, with an iterated reasoning, $$ det(A^{k}) = det(A)^{k} $$

Now, you need to prove that $det(A) \neq 0 \Leftrightarrow A$ is invertible. You can take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391118/if-a-is-invertible-show-that-deta-neq-0/391135#391135).

Answer (score 13):

Let $B$ be the inverse of $A^{2014}$. This means
$$A^{2014}B = I$$
Based on the above equation, you want to find a $C$ such that
$$AC = I$$
So your task is to figure out what $C$ is from the first equation.

Answer (score 9):

As help, consider $AB$ invertible, which means we can find $C$ with $(AB)C=I$ then can you use associativity to show $A$ is invertible? If $B=A$ what does this mean? Can you see how you could apply this to your problem by choosing $B$ appropriately?

Answer (score 1):

And yet another way of looking at this:

Saying that an element $a$ is invertible in a ring $R$ is equivalent to saying that multiplication by that element $R → R, x ↦ ax$ is invertible/bijective.

If $A^{2014}$ is invertible, then multiplying by $A^{2014}$ is bijective which is the $2014$-fold self-composition of multiplying by $A$. So multiplying by $A$ must be bijective as well, meaning $A$ is invertible.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way. $A$ is invertible iff $Ax=0$ implies $x=0$. Assume that $A^{2014}$ is invertible. Suppose that $Ax=0$. Then $A^{2014}x=A^{2013}Ax=0$, which implies $x=0$ because $A^{2014}$ is invertible. So $Ax=0$ implies $x=0$, which means $A$ is invertible.